# Animated placemark icon in kml Google Earth?

Tags: image, animation, kml, google-earth

How can I have animated icons for placemark in Google Earth?

I tried using network link and changing the icon in the networked kml file but that creates a flicker in the placemark. Google Earth also does not support Animated gif's which would be my best option.

Is there a way to show animated gifs or something similar in Google Earth. Maybe I am working in the wrong direction with the placemarks and I should use something else?

My use case is that I want to create animated weather icons like cloud icon with rain drops moving as shown on news channels.

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth doesn't support animated gifs so that is a non-starter, sorry.

The only other option you have is via KML, either using NetworkLinks (as you have tried) or via the various [time and animation elements](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/time).  See the [`<TimeStamp>`](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#timestamp) element in the KML 2.2 Reference for examples.